# Is it possible to run selenium as a windows service using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, windows-services, selenium-chromedriver

I want my windows service to use selenium for some automation inside a website, is there a way to achieve this? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I use [Selenium.WebDriver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver).  It is easy to implement and it doesn't need to run Selenium server.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras I want to use Selenium web driver not selenium server, or is it the only option?

Comment: @DavidPivovar I use Selenium.WebDriver right now it doesn't work within a window service, does it work for you running as a service?

Comment: No it is not possible as it's shown in the answers. There are some applicaitons and workarounds but I haven't used them and I can't vouch for them.